# Calling a cloud function from a firebase web app

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to make use of a cloud function in a firebase web app and am facing some problems. If someone can point out some settings or other things I may be missing that would be helpful.

First here is the relevant code for the cloud function:

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  const from = req.body.sender;
  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
      .then(function(userRecord) {
       console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
      });
});
```

Second here is the code in the web app calling the cloud function:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/myFunc", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    from: "example@example.com"
}));
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log('THE DATA:',data);
};
```

And finally this is the message I see in the web console after firing the call by hitting a button:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/myFunc. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 408.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/myFunc. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

There is nothing relevant in the server logs at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time spent I found out that if I write my cloud function this way, it works:

```
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    const from = String(req.query.from); // Through the URL.
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", 
                      userRecord.toJSON());
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: @abraham's solution is more preferable if you are using the function within your web app only and not as an api end point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install cors and use it something like this,

```js
import * as cors from "cors"; 
const corsHandler = cors({ origin: true });
 
// allow cors in http function 
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => { 
      corsHandler(req, res, async () => { 
              // your method body 
      });
});
```

Comment: OK. Then I will need to check how to install cors. I have done something like that before but it was with a php function.

Comment: You can run "npm install cors"

Comment: Yes I will do that. In the meanwhile I had a lood at two samples https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/time-server and https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint. I was able to make the first one work not the second.

Comment: I have changed my code to fit your recommendations. But I still get in the web console in my browser this error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/myFunc. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 408.". Note though that I no longer get the second error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS Callable function to let Firebase handle the request/response.

```js
// function
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const from = data.sender;
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(from)
      .then(function(userRecord) {
       console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
       return { user: userRecord.toJSON() }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
      });
});
```

```js
// web
 import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
 import { getFunctions } from 'firebase/functions';

const app = initializeApp({
     // ...
   });
const functions = getFunctions(app);
const myFunc = httpsCallable(functions, 'myFunc');
myFunc({ sender: 'example@example.com' })
  .then((result) => {
    const data = result.data;
    console.log(data.user);
  });
```